# Rails - Get records of a specific id and store it in an Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord

How do I get records from a table with a specific ID and store these records in an Array?

For better understanding I try to explain it to you more clear:

Imagine a table with the following columns: **(ID,FIX_ID,AMOUNT)**

where **ID** is an unique ID which always will auto_incremented by 1.

**FIX_ID** is an ID which can appear multiple times in the table.

And **AMOUNT** is just a simple type which represents the amount of some "things".

---

So all I want to get now is every record from the table which have the **FIX_ID** that I am looking for.
Remember: The **FIX_ID** is not unique => it can appear multiple times.

And that's it. So imagine that I want to get all records with the **FIX_ID** of 10. All these records which I will get should be stored in an Array.

My question to you: Is it possible to realize this "request" to the database with ActiveRecord?
If so, then how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get an [ActiveRecord::Relation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html) object like this:

```
ModelName.where('FIX_ID = ?', 10)
```

Relation object will perform a database query as soon as you call methods like `all`, `each` or `any?` on it. If you really need an array, call `to_a` on that Relation:

```
ModelName.where('FIX_ID = ?', 10).to_a
```